# Word for “minimal object” in category theory

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Is there a word for an object which has no morphism (other than the identity) pointing to it?

Comment: @DanRust while I cannot attest to any usage, I was going to make the same suggestion.

Comment: One might go with an approximation of the graph terminology and call it a source.

Comment: @DanRust Why isolated when it could have arrows out of it? If we remove the identity then it becomes precisely a source. But being isolated would not in my mind exclude having nontrivial endomorphisms.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah sorry I read the question wrong, you're right!

Comment: I doubt there's a word for when you require the morphisms to the object to be identities. If you relax the condition so that the morphisms to the objects are isomorphisms, then when the category has an initial object, such a "minimal object" is known as a *strict initial object*. If you really need a word for your minimal objects, I would suggest "empty object" since your condition amounts to requiring that the object have no generalized elements other than the tautological one.